# How to put correlation analysis results in a csv table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, export, export-to-csv, correlation

In R, I need to put the results of a correlation analysis between two variables in a table.csv file. The original dataframe is made up of three columns: the first column (group) contains the group to which the observations belongs, while the other two columns (var1 and var2) contains the values of the two variables.

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("G1", "G2"), each = 10),
                 var1 = rnorm(20),
                 var2 = rnorm(20))
```

I conducted the correlation analysis by group.

```
spear <- by(df, df$group, FUN = function(X) cor.test(X$var1, X$var2, method = "spearman"))
```

And I got this output:

```
spear
#df$group: G1
#   Spearman's rank correlation rho
#data:  X$var1 and X$var2
#S = 144, p-value = 0.7329
#alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
#sample estimates:
#      rho 
#0.1272727 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#df$group: G2
#   Spearman's rank correlation rho
#data:  X$var1 and X$var2
#S = 122, p-value = 0.4697
#alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
#sample estimates:
#      rho 
#0.2606061
```

Now I need to obtain a table, with the first row as header, in csv format, with the id of the group in the first column, the rho value for that group in the second column, and the p-value for that group in the third column. The table should look like this:

```
group,rho,pvalue
G1,0.1272727,0.7329
G2,0.2606061,0.4697
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dataframe in your `by` function extracting the values that you want.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, by(df, df$group, FUN = function(x) {
  tmp <- cor.test(x$var1, x$var2, method = "spearman")
  data.frame(group = x$group[1], rho = tmp$estimate, p.value = tmp$p.value)
}))
result
#   group    rho p.value
#G1    G1 -0.261   0.470
#G2    G2 -0.442   0.204
```

To write the data to csv we can use `write.csv` :

```
write.csv(result, 'result.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah. Can you please add the command line to write the output on a csv file?

Comment: You can use `write.csv` to write output to csv file. Updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 2):

The `spear` object is a list of two lists (one `htest` list for each group):

```
str(spear)
List of 2
 $ G1:List of 8
  ..$ statistic  : Named num 140
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  ..$ parameter  : NULL
  ..$ p.value    : num 0.682
  ..$ estimate   : Named num 0.152
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
  ..$ null.value : Named num 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
  ..$ alternative: chr "two.sided"
  ..$ method     : chr "Spearman's rank correlation rho"
  ..$ data.name  : chr "X$var1 and X$var2"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
 $ G2:List of 8
  ..$ statistic  : Named num 180
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  ..$ parameter  : NULL
  ..$ p.value    : num 0.811
  ..$ estimate   : Named num -0.0909
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
  ..$ null.value : Named num 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
  ..$ alternative: chr "two.sided"
  ..$ method     : chr "Spearman's rank correlation rho"
  ..$ data.name  : chr "X$var1 and X$var2"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
 - attr(*, "dim")= int 2
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ df$group: chr [1:2] "G1" "G2"
 - attr(*, "call")= language by.data.frame(data = df, INDICES = df$group, FUN = function(X) cor.test(X$var1,      X$var2, method = "spearman"))
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "by"
```

The `tidy` function from the `broom` package can convert an `htest` list to a data.frame (a tibble really).

```
library(broom)
lapply(spear, tidy)
$G1
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  estimate statistic p.value method                          alternative
     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                           <chr>      
1    0.152       140   0.682 Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  

$G2
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  estimate statistic p.value method                          alternative
     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                           <chr>      
1  -0.0909       180   0.811 Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided
```

You still have a list, but it is much more workable. With some `dplyr` functions, we can make this list look like what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(spear, tidy) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate(group = names(spear)) %>%
  rename(rho = estimate) %>%
  select(group, rho, p.value)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  group     rho p.value
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 G1     0.152    0.682
2 G2    -0.0909   0.811
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply()` to extract values from the output objects, convert them to data frames, and write the combined data frame to a csv file.

```
set.seed(95014) # to make example reproducible
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("G1", "G2"), each = 10),
                 var1 = rnorm(20),
                 var2 = rnorm(20))

spear <- by(df, df$group, FUN = function(X) cor.test(X$var1, X$var2, method = "spearman"))
```

At this point the object `spear` is a list that contains one element per by group. We will process each element, extracting the required elements and returning them as a list of objects of type `data.frame()`.

Since the elements in the list are named by group, we use `unique(df$group)` to drive `lapply()`, enabling us to assign the names as a column in the output data frames.

```
# convert to data frame 
dfList <- lapply(unique(df$group),function(x){
     y <- spear[[x]]
     data.frame(group = x,
                rho_value = y$estimate,
                p_value = y$p.value)
})
```

Finally, we use `do.call()` to bind the list of data frames as the first argument to `write.csv()`, resulting in a single data frame that is then written to disk in comma separated values format.

```
write.csv(do.call(rbind,dfList),"./data/rhoCalcs.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

...and the output:

```
"group","rho_value","p_value"
"G1",0.260606060606061,0.469675250206491
"G2",0.333333333333333,0.348846243872153
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `sapply` instead of `by`.

```
gu <- unique(df$group)  ## putting the groups into a vector
r <- sapply(gu, function(x) 
  cor.test(~ var1 + var2, df[df$group == x, ], method="spearman")[c("estimate", "p.value")])
r <- cbind(group=gu, matrix(unlist(r), 2, b=T, dimnames=list(NULL, c("rho", "p_value"))))
write.csv(r, file="xyz.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Alternatively, if you need to do that more often, you could wrap it in a small function.

```
my.cor.test <- function(x) {
  ct <- cor.test(~ var1 + var2, df[df$group == x, ], 
                 method="spearman")[c("estimate", "p.value")]
  setNames(c(x, unlist(ct)), c("group", "rho", "p_value"))
}

gu <- unique(df$group)  ## putting unique groups into a vector
r <- t(sapply(gu, my.cor.test))
write.csv(r, file="xyz.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

#### Gives

```
group,rho,p_value
G1,-0.696969696969697,0.0311410954595681
G2,0.0545454545454545,0.891638843953118
```